# Insert data to transaction with OP_RETURN

Tags: bitcoind, op-return

This might be a possible duplicate with [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25224/what-is-a-step-by-step-way-to-insert-data-in-op-return).

I want to know a proper way to insert additional string with OP_RETURN and retrieve the transaction from block chain and decode it accordingly.

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

#### How do I add metadata to the blockchain?

Essentially, one of the output [scripts](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script) should be

```
OP_RETURN <the data you want to add>
```

That's it.

Let me give an example. Say you want to add the string "Melons." to the blockchain.

1. Convert to binary
   "Melons." -> `4d656c6f6e732e`
2. Add the push-data-onto-stack command at the start. This is the length of your metadata if it's less than 75 bytes, or OP_PUSHDATAx otherwise.
   `074d656c6f6e732e`
3. Add OP_RETURN at the start
   `6a074d656c6f6e732e`
4. Put this in the scriptPubKey of an output of a transaction. I wrote a guide on this [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/36439/2306).

#### How do I find it again?

That's... trickier. Bitcoin is not optimized for searching the metadata of transactions.

Possibilities:

- Look through all of the transactions you get with something like `bitcointools`.
- Use a website like [coinsecrets.org](http://coinsecrets.org).

Comment: So to find the data again, we should traverse through the blockchain, find OP_RETURN patterns, grab associated data, index them ..., right?

Answer (score 1):

You might find our OP_RETURN libraries useful, for [PHP](https://github.com/coinspark/php-OP_RETURN) and [Python](https://github.com/coinspark/python-OP_RETURN). If you look at the code you can also see exactly how they work.