# Send BTC with attachment using BitcoinJ

Tags: bitcoinj

is there an example of how using BitcoinJ send BTC with an attachment?
 Lets say I want to write to blockchain "Vaclav Bilek Born 1991". 
If I understand it correctly, its just about sending minimum bitcoins possible with current minimum fee? 
Is here a way how to do this in BitcoinJ ?
Usual syntax of sending BTC allow me only to send BTC like this:

```
kit.wallet().sendCoins(kit.peerGroup(), to, value);
```

How to achieve adding attachment? And how long can the attachment be? What if I want to send longer attachment, is here standardised way how to do that? Or I just make two TX and tell the people who I wants to see it, that one half is in TX1321... and other hald in TX3214... ?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert data to transaction with OP\_RETURN](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/31989/insert-data-to-transaction-with-op-return)

Comment: Hello, its not duplicate since link you gave me is not connected with BitcoinJ, I dont ask how to do that in general, I ask how to do that using given framework.