# BitCoin API C# - can I create transaction, add IO, sign, get hex?

Tags: transactions, api

I am using [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/30834/create-op-return-tx-with-bitcoinjs-lib) link as a demonstration of what I want to achieve (see code below).

I am not in a position to use node.js now - and I need to use C#.

I have looked at the [bitcoin.info API](https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-csharp)

My Question: would the C# BitCoin API be able to do the same where I build up the transaction, add the inputs, add the output, sign the transaction and then get the hex?

Is there sample code that someone can refer me to please?

```
var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib')

var tx = new bitcoin.Transaction()

// Add the input (who is paying) of the form [previous transaction hash, index of the output to use]
tx.addInput("aa94ab02c182214f090e99a0d57021caffd0f195a81c24602b1028b130b63e31", 0)

// Add the output (who to pay to) of the form [payee's address, amount in satoshis]
tx.addOutput("THEADDRESS", 15000)

// Initialize a private key using WIF
key = bitcoin.ECKey.fromWIF("L1uyy5qTuGrVXrmrsvHWHgVzW9kKdrp27wBC7Vs6nZDTF2BRUVwy")

// Sign the first input with the new key
tx.sign(0, key)

// Print transaction serialized as hex
console.log(tx.toHex())
// => 0100000001313eb630b128102b60241ca895f1d0ffca2170d5a0990e094f2182c102ab94aa000000008a47304402200169f1f844936dc60df54e812345f5dd3e6681fea52e33c25154ad9cc23a330402204381ed8e73d74a95b15f312f33d5a0072c7a12dd6c3294df6e8efbe4aff27426014104e75628573696aed32d7656fb35e9c71ea08eb6492837e13d2662b9a36821d0fff992692fd14d74fdec20fae29128ba12653249cbeef521fc5eba84dde0689f27ffffffff01983a0000000000001976a914ad618cf4333b3b248f9744e8e81db2964d0ae39788ac00000000

// You could now push the transaction onto the Bitcoin network manually (see https://blockchain.info/pushtx)
```